# When a natural map is an isomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an $R$-module. Set $M^+:=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(M,{\mathbb {Q/Z}})$. Since $\mathbb {Q/Z}$ is an injective cogenerator, we know that the natural map $M\rightarrow M^{++}$ is an injective R-module homomorphism.

1. If $R=\mathbb Z$ I can show that if M is a finite R-module then it is an isomorphism. ($(\mathbb Z/p^i\mathbb Z)^+\cong \mathbb Z/p^i\mathbb Z$).
2. In general, when is the natural map an isomorphism?
3. If M is a simple R-module is $M^+$ a simple R-module?

Comment: Do you mean finitely generated as an $R$-module or as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: @M.Van as R module,thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of $R$. I mean, in the expression expression $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,\mathbb{Q/Z})$ there is no mention of $R$. Do you mean that we should take the underlying abelian group or replace $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ by another injective co-generator ? In the former, everything will fail if $M$ is not finitely generated as an $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Take for example $R=\mathbb{Q}[X]$ (a p.i.d) and $M=R$, or even $R=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (a field) and $M=R$.

Comment: @Roland quite right,I will correct it.every R module is a $\mathbb Z$R bimodule,We can think M is right R moudle,and Hom is homomorphism between Abelian group.thank you very much!

Comment: @Roland I have realized my error,even if we take $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Z$,this is also not isomorphism.

Comment: I know that if $M$ is a $R$-module, you can endow $M^{++}$ with a structure of $R$-module such that $M\rightarrow M^{++}$ is a map of $R$-modules, but this map being an isomorphism has nothing to do with $R$, so I still don't understand the purpose of $R$. You can just take $R$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$ and you will have exactly the same answer to your three questions.